# Append and Clear Text File Web Form C#

Tags: c#, webforms

There is an existing process that is writing to a text file on my site.  Let's say the file is at http://www.mysite.com/addresses/addresses.txt

I have been able to successfully display the contents of the file in a text box using client.DownloadString, however I can't find a clear answer on how to append to the end of this text file and also to clear the contents of this file.  This is a text file on my web server.

I'm working in C#.  I do know the path to the file on the server at c:\inetpub\site\addresses\address.txt as well.

Any ideas on how to append or clear this file?  Everything I seem to find on it is on windows forms and i don't use enough DotNet to know where to look.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Writing files to your web server from your web site is probably a bad approach.

Comment: Just an FYI: a problem may arrise because the file is in use by whatever program is writing the file.  You may not be able to modify it (it really depends how that process is handling the file).

Comment: Another page on the site is writing it and this will be a hidden page accessed by only 1 person once a month.  I realize it isn't full proof but the chances of problems are somewhat minimized

Comment: You should be using a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Article [CodeSnip: Read and Write Text Files with ASP.NET 2.0](http://aspalliance.com/544_CodeSnip_Read_and_Write_Text_Files_with_ASPNET_20)

```
System.IO.StreamWriter StreamWriter1 = 
new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("test.txt"));
StreamWriter1.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
StreamWriter1.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you, article was just what I needed!